# version change issues of angular and node

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^11.0.0-next || >=11.0.0 <12.0.0,
but Angular version 13.0.0 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/

can any one help to fix

Answer (score 0):

If you run command `ng update @angular/<package-name>@<version>` cli automatically will install a compatible version of cli (*temporary*) and will do the update.

For example for upgrading `@angular/core` from `11.0.0` to `12.0.0` when the latest version is `13.0.0` you have to run:

```
ng update @angular/core@12.0.0
```

If it shows error try running with `--force` flag as below:

```
ng update @angular/core@12.0.0 --force
```